# I am trying to enable the jQuery UI module, but I am hitting with error

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to enable the Jquery UI module in drupal 7, but I am hitting with error: The jQuery UI plugin is missing. Download and extract it to your jquery_ui module directory. (Currently using jQuery UI Not found)

I downloaded and extracted the plugin from the link into my Jquery_UI folder in sites/all/modules/jquery_ui. still I could not enable the module.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the module is expecting this structure:

`modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/(actual jquery ui files)`

However, it looks like jQuery UI library removed the version.txt file that this module checks for. If it does not find that text file, it considers the plugin 'not installed' which is kind of a bad check.

People are talking about it here, with a fix for Drupal 6 (and some talk for 7): https://www.drupal.org/node/1954136

However the project page advises you to use jQuery Update instead:

> Drupal 7+ Since Drupal 7 ships with jQuery UI, the jQuery UI module
>   has been deprecated and moved to the jQuery Update module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update

You should dump this module and use jQuery Update and go from there.